# How to pass the whole dataframe and the index of the row being operated upon to the apply() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I pass the whole dataframe and the index of the row being operated upon when using the `apply()` method on a dataframe?

Specifically, I have a dataframe `correlation_df` with the following data:

| id | scores | cosine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 0.8 |
| 2 | 75 | 0.7 |
| 3 | 50 | 0.4 |
| 4 | 25 | 0.05 |

I want to create an extra column where each row value is the correlation of `scores` and `cosine` without that row's values included.

My understanding is that I should do this with with a custom function and the apply method, i.e. `correlation_df.apply(my_fuct)`. However, I need to pass in the whole dataframe and the index of the row in question so that I can ignore it in the correlation calculation.

NB. Problem code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

score = np.array([100, 75, 50, 25])
cosine = np.array([.8, 0.7, 0.4, .05])
correlation_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "score": score,
        "cosine": cosine,
    }
)
corr = correlation_df.corr().values[0, 1]
```

**[Edit]** Roundabout solution that I'm sure can be improved:

```
def my_fuct(row):
    i = int(row["index"])
    r = list(range(correlation_df.shape[0]))
    r.remove(i)
    subset = correlation_df.iloc[r, :].copy()
    subset = subset.set_index("index")
    return subset.corr().values[0, 1]

correlation_df["diff_correlations"] =  = correlation_df.apply(my_fuct, axis=1)
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include a better way of doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be simplified to:

```
>>> df["diff_correlations"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.drop(x.name).corr().iat[0,1], axis=1)
>>> df
   score  cosine  diff_correlations
0    100    0.80           0.999015
1     75    0.70           0.988522
2     50    0.40           0.977951
3     25    0.05           0.960769
```

A more sophisticated method would be:

- The whole correlation matrix isn't made every time this way.

```
df.apply(lambda x: (tmp_df := df.drop(x.name)).score.corr(tmp_df.cosine), axis=1)
```

---

The index can be accessed in an apply with `.name` or `.index`, depending on the axis:

```
>>> correlation_df.apply(lambda x: x.name, axis=1)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
>>> correlation_df.apply(lambda x: x.index, axis=0)
   score  cosine
0      0       0
1      1       1
2      2       2
3      3       3
```

Answer (score -1):

Using

```py
correlation_df = correlation_df.reset_index()
```

gives you a new column `index`, denoting the index of the row, namely what previously was your index. Now when using `pd.apply` access it via:

```py
correlation_df.apply(lambda r: r["index"])
```

After you are done you could do:

```
correlation_df = correlation_df.set_index("index")
```

to get your previous format back.

Comment: I don't think that `correlation_df.apply(correlation_df, lambda r: r["index"])` is the correct usage of the `apply` method signature? However, I did use the idea of converting the index into a column in a rather roundabout solution I came up with (and will add to the original question). A more succinct solution would still be great!